# Join in R fails even though logical comparisons are true

Tags: r, join, data.table, dplyr, sqldf

**The data is sensitive and can't be published, the answer will be in the form of guesswork, which I will be perfectly happy  with.**

I'm trying to join a larger data.table with a smaller, and update some values. The smaller is loaded from a Excel spreadsheet via XLConnect.

The join is something like this:

`d.tmp2 <- left_join(d.main, d.wb, by = c("Nr" = "Nr"))`

The code executes but I don't get any matches (only NA:s), which is weird since these sample rows returns `TRUE` (as it should):

`d.wb[1]$Nr == d.main[39]$Nr`

```
[1] TRUE
```

**Edit:**

The problem is solved in itself and has to do with how joins in R are handled. The encoding in the data were displayed as "Unknown" but still UTF-8 while the data table imported from Excel was explicitly set to UTF-8. Apperently it's fine to do logical comparisons with different(not really different) encodings but not joins.

Setting the encoding with iconv solved this. Still, I don't understand why logical comparisons and joins differ this much, it makes little sense to me. There is probably something I don't understand working here.

Comment: If we can't [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), it will be just guesswork.

Comment: @zx8754 Yeah I know, but I don't see how I can reproduce it. 
1) The data is sensitive, I can't post it publicly 
2) The data and system probably needs to be exact for us to reproduce is it and that's not possibly

So I happily settle for guesswork - I'm guessing something with encoding. It usually is when the errors are weird in R.

Comment: I actually got a solution, below. I had to re-set the encoding to UTF-8 in `d.main` with iconv, and then the join worked. I guess the logical comparison is less picky with encoding, while joins are?

 `d.wb[1]` does in fact return 1 st row and str of `d.wb` returns the different columns and their values as well as the rest it should return

Comment: why don't you use `data.table::merge` and `by.x` and `by.y` to join your `data.tables` ?

Comment: @Cath I rather would but I find the dplyr variant easier to read/understand,  more lika a sql-join in written syntax. That might have changed in a dev version?  

If the data.tables were large I would do it, even so.

Comment: well I don't see the point of loading `dplyr` to do a join on `data.tables` when `data.table::merge` does what you need : for a left join : `merge(d.main, d.wb, all.x=TRUE, by.x = "Nr", by.y = "Nr")` though here you can just put `by="Nr"` as both colnames are the same

Comment: +1 You'r right of course, in a future commit I might change it since dplyr-join is used quite a lot in that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After som testing I found the answer, I had to create a new column in d.main, again convert to UTF-8 using iconv and then join on the new variable. Then it worked.

So the error was with encoding, but I still don't see why the result from the logical comparison and dplyr's join are so different...

Answer (score 0):

with dplyr

```
d.tmp2 <- left_join(d.main, d.wb, by = "Nr")
```

with base R

```
d.tmp2 <- merge(d.main, d.wb, by = "Nr")
```

should work.

Comment: Yeah I know - it should work but it doesn't. This is weirding me out - is the logical comparison less sensitive than dplyr or base joins, I just tried setting some of them explicitly and that worked as well (d.main[Nr == d.wb[19]$Nr, var_a := new value])